# useEffect goes in an infinite loop. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

Please alter this code so that useEffect does not keep calling itself again and again. Here, I am fetching data from the backend and updating state within the useEffect, which itself is the dependency. Is there some easy way to fix it?

My use case:
I use a form to add a post and once I submit the form, I want it to show the updated list of posts right away. 'Posts' is a component where the updated list of posts are passed as props and each individual post is rendered within component 'Post'. So, I want to pass the updated list of post to 'Posts' once the form is submitted

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function readPosts(){
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(backendLink + '/post/profile/read');
        setPosts(res.data.posts);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    readPosts();
  }, [posts])
```

Comment: Remove `posts` from the dependencies. Now it reruns `useEffect` every time `posts` changes, and the effect changes `posts`, hence the infinite loop. Add whatever other dependency if you need to rerun it.

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function readPosts(){
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(backendLink + '/post/profile/read');
        setPosts(res.data.posts);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    readPosts();
  }, []) // Change here
```

Comment: I don't want to call it only within the first render though

Comment: When _do_ you want to call it then? What's your use-case? @FiFi

Comment: Then don't use useEffect and make a function which call readPost when button press.

Comment: I use a form to add a post and once I submit the form, I want it to show the updated list of posts right away. 'Posts' is a component where the updated list of posts are passed as props and each individual post is rendered within component 'Post'. So, I want to pass the updated list of post to 'Posts' once the form is submitted

Comment: @FiFi Then you need to explain the entire process when asking questions or we don't know about it. You can still update your code to show what you are doing right now. I mean the whole process

Comment: Oops, updated it. So, is there any way to re-render the Posts component once the form is submitted?

Comment: @Khant is correct. Use a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array when the component renders to get the posts you need from your server, and add them to state. And when you click your submit button have a function that a) makes a POST request with that data, and b) updates the state. When the state changes the component will re-render, and that updated state will be passed down to the `Posts` component in its props.

Comment: @Andy Got what I needed with your latest response. Thank you so much Khant and Andy.

Comment: No worries. Happy coding. @FiFi.

Comment: @Gass I did but I do not have enough points to cast it. I'm still new to the community.

Answer (score 0):

This is whats happening right now in your code.

useEffect fires when the "posts" value change.
the useEffect changes the "posts"
which triggers useEffect because useEffect changed "posts"

this is an infinite loop. remove [posts] from dependency and find a workaround.